# Открытие картинки по ссылке в переменной Django

Tags: python, django

Не могу добиться чтобы картинка открывалась по ссылке.

Файл views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import os

def partners(request):
    files = os.listdir('static/img')
    dict = {}
    for file in files:
        dict[file[:len(file)-4]] = '.com'
    return render(request, 'partners/partners.html', context={'r':dict})
```

файл HTML

```
{% for key, value in r.items %}
  <a href="http://{{key}}{{value}}" target="_blank"><img src="{% static 'img/{{key}}.png' %}" alt="Acer"></a>
{% endfor %}
```

Словарь dict `{'acer': '.com', ...}`
Ссылка из `href` срабатывает, а вот картинка из `src` не подтягивается.
Static в settings.py подключен. Может кто подскажет в чем проблема?

Comment: Для начала хотя бы просто откройте картинку по этой ссылке и покажите нам текст ошибки, а также расскажите, как вы запускаете джангу и включен ли дебаг

Comment: В том-то и дело, что если прописать src="{% static 'img/acer.png' %}" то она открывается

Comment: А, ну да, такой синтаксис вложенных друг в друга тегов в шаблоне не работает ведь. Почему бы не собрать все нужные ссылки заранее во вьюхе?